# Autocomplete fields with database in Drupal content type

Tags: php, sql, database, drupal, drupal-7

I started to create a new content type with modules Field Group and Field Collection and it's worked !

But, I would like to add autocomplete fields in my form and I don't find how to do this. Maybe  using a hook_form_alter however I can't add my custom fields in my field collection.

You know how to do this ?

Thanks a lot

PS: I work with D7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add an auto_complete to a from field, you need to do the following:

1st: use hook_for_alter() to add the auto_complete path to the text field

```
function YOUR_MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{
    if($form_id == "YOUR-CONTENT-TYPE_node_form")
    {
        $form['field_YOUR-FIELD']['und'][0]['value']['#autocomplete_path'] = 'my-module/autocomplete/path';
    }
}
```

2nd: use hook_menu() to define the menu callback you passed as the #autocomplete_path property to the field

```
function YOUR_MODULE_menu()
{
    $items = array();
    $items['my-module/autocomplete/path'] = array(
    'page callback'     => 'your_module_autocomplete_callback',
    'access callback'   => TRUE,
    'weight'            => 1,
    'type'              => MENU_CALLBACK,
    );
    return $items;
}
```

3rd and last: add you menu callback function which returns the items to the textfield

```
function your_module_autocomplete_callback($string)
{
    $items = array();
    $query = db_select('node', 'n');
    $value = $query->fields('n', array('title'));
    $value = $query->condition(db_and()->condition('n.type', 'YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE')->condition('title', '%' . db_like($string) . '%', 'LIKE'))->orderRandom()->execute();

    $i = 0;
    foreach ($value as $val)
    {
        $items[$val->name] = check_plain($val->name);
    }
    print drupal_json_output($items);
    exit();
}
```

Hope this helps... Muhammad.

Comment: Hi and thank you for this help ! But i'm sorry i've another problem : In fact, when i've created my form i've used the module "Field Group" and the other module "Field collection". You can see my form configuration [Here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Cu1zuKaWF97J5LujfMv-lW7YOTENDtLALAPDQUO0tIA/edit). My goal is to convert the field_adversaires in an autocomplete field but I can't... I think it's my groups the problem... An idea ?

Comment: The link isn't working. can you find another way to upload it?!

Comment: which field you wanna add autocomplete to ?!

Comment: It's in my first comment, I would like convert the field field_adversaires in an autocomplete field. Thanks for your attention

Comment: I have understand how this fields work ! In fact, must put $form['field_match']['und'][0]['field_adversaires']['und'][0]['value']['#autocomplete_path'] = 'basketfacile_type/autocomplete'; to make it work. Next it's ok ! thanx for your help

Comment: Hi ! I'm sorry but I've another problem... My autocomplete fields works but when I click on the button "add another item" it disappear... I make a loop "for" to resolve my problem, it's work but other fields appear as u can see [HERE](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Cu1zuKaWF97J5LujfMv-lW7YOTENDtLALAPDQUO0tIA/edit). An idea to resolve that ?

Comment: Hi, I have added that in another answer. Kindly check the code sample. -Muhammad.

Answer (score 1):

the updated code that fits multiple fields.

```
function YOUR_MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{
    if($form_id == "YOUR-CONTENT-TYPE_node_form")
    {
        foreach($form['field_match']['und'][0]['field_adversaires']['und'] as $k =>$v)
        {
            if(is_numeric($k))
            {
                $form['field_match']['und'][0]['field_adversaires']['und'][$k]['value']['#autocomplete_path'] = 'basketfacile_type/autocomplete';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it works for you... Muhammad.

Comment: Thanks it works ! Just an "error" in your code the foreach loop is : foreach($form['field_match']['und'][0]['field_adversaires']['und'] as $k =>$v){
                if(is_numeric($v)){
                    $form['field_match']['und'][$v]['field_adversaires']['und'][0]['value']['#autocomplete_path'] = 'basketfacile_type/autocomplete/field_adversaires';
                }
            } But it's ok for my module thank you !

Comment: Thanks for letting me know it worked. Excuse me for any code typos, I didn't have the chance to test my code. -Muhammad.